# Copying data from text file to array

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy data from text file to array, I got error `Index was outside the bounds of the array`.

```
    Dim vstring(-1) As String
    Dim vid(-1) As String
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim vText As String = ""
    Dim vFileName As String = "C:\Users\suman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ass3_2076004\student.txt"

    Dim vAvgValue As Integer
    Dim vErrorMsg As String = ""
    If (Txt_IdNumber.Text).Length = 5 Then

        Dim rvSR As New IO.StreamReader(vFileName)
        Do While rvSR.Peek <> -1
            vText = rvSR.ReadLine()
            vstring = vText.Split(",")
            vid(index) = vstring(0)'error 
            index = index + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: Your arrays aren't big enough.  Use `List(Of String)`.

Comment: check your vText.Length ... what result ?

Comment: If you're reading a CSV file, don't use .Split(). Really. It's wrong for that. Look at TextFieldParser or other dedicated csv parser. They're _faster_ and, more importantly, correctly account for all the edge cases in CSV.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of a few lines of your data file. It sounds like it is something like this: student name, other stuff [crlf] student name, other stuff [crlf]

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim vstring() as String
Dim vFileName As String = "C:\Users\suman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ass3_2076004\student.txt"

If Txt_IdNumber.Text.Length = 5 Then
    Using rvSR As New IO.StreamReader(vFileName)
        vstring = rvSR.ReadLines().Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c)(0)).ToArray()
    End Using
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably declare vstring as an unsized array.  Like this:

```
Dim vString() as string
```

Second, Since you don't know how many lines you need, declare vid as list.  Like this:

```
Dim vid as List(of string)
```

Then, before you split the string, you should make sure it actually contains a comma.  Like this:

```
    Do While rvSR.Peek <> -1
        vText = rvSR.ReadLine()
        If vText.Contains(",") Then
           vstring = vText.Split(",")
           vid.add(vstring(0)) 
        End If
    Loop
    'at the end, you can convert vid from a list to an array, if you want 
    Dim arr() as string = vid.ToArray()
```